# PHP+Stomp+ActiveMq, "AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" not working

Tags: php, delay, message-queue, stomp

I'm using laravel framework based on php.And Stomp+activeMQ.
Here I need to send something into mq, however the message should be consumed after 180 seconds, not immediately.

Option1, I send it with a timestamp, and the consumer will check the timestamp.If interval > 180, then do something and ack().

Option1 is inefficient, for every moment the consumer is checking timestamp but very few messages are acked.

Option2, shell_exec("php send.php | at now + 3 minute"), it looks strange.

Are there any better solutions?

I have set "AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" according to Lee's advice, however the message will be sent immediately, too.Maybe the delay config can only be used to PUB/SUB but not PTP？Here is my code:

```
        $con = new Stomp(config('app.mq_url'));
        if (!$con->isConnected()) {
            $con->connect();
            $con->setReadTimeout(3);
        }
        $con->begin("Transaction");
        $options =[
            'persistent'=> $persistent,
            'AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY' => $delay * 1000
        ];
        $con->send($queue, json_encode($params), $options);
        $con->commit("Transaction");
        $con->disconnect();
        $con->send($queue, json_encode($params), $options);
```

And I remember to set schedulerSupport=true in activemq.xml.

I refer to this: [ActiveMq Doc](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html), is this concerned? I don't know.Or is it OK to send 'AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY' in header? Because [ActiveMq Doc: Stomp](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) does not list it as a header.

> Check your Message Properties
>   The message property scheduledJobId is reserved for use by the Job Scheduler. If this property is set before sending, the message will be sent immediately and not scheduled. Also, after a scheduled message is received, the property scheduledJobId will be set on the received message so keep this in mind if using something like a Camel Route which might automatically copy properties over when re-sending a message.

Comment: ActiveMQ supports delayed/scheduled delivery, so just set the correct option when sending the message to AMQ. Here's a laravel stomp queue adapter that implements delayed delivery: https://github.com/mayconbordin/l5-stomp-queue/blob/master/src/StompQueue.php#L177

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you.

Comment: However, it does not work in my project.Sad

Comment: maybe try an run the phpscript as a supervisor task (http://supervisord.org/)

Answer (score 0):

edit activemq.xml enable broker schedulerSupport="true"

eg.

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
```

then restart your activemq server